# Large ECommerce Workload with Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, e-commerce

I'm tasked with building a large eCommerce site for a retailer. We are using packaged software for it. The package is difficult to tailor, and inflexible, but it scales on a solidly tested java application.

In the background though, I've been considering trying to use this as a reference workload to build a custom Ruby on Rails eCommerce application - just for interest sake and to learn the framework. But before I start too far down the path, I guess I'm looking for a high level is determination if it's even possible to reach this type of workload with ROR.

The app would have to capture about 2000 orders per hour, but each order is big, so would be processing about 140,000 line items per hour. Concurrent customers are relatively straightforward, at about 5,000 active in an hour. But browse to shop is high, with a conversion of about 45% of customers coming to the site to shop so majority of processing is order capture rather than search & browse of most sites.

So my question is, what is "large workload" when it comes to ROR? Is this a feasible NFR to meet with a ROR application? What considerations should I make?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately, your question is not a good fit for this site as it not an actual software development problem, but concerns the rather broad and unspecific area or language choices that are frowned upon here. That said, 1 order every 2 seconds is hardly a "large workload", you probably wouldn't even need to start optimizing at that load.

Comment: Holger, thanks, normally I would say you're right, 1 order every 2 seconds is a small workload. But when you measure in lines per hour rather than orders per hour, 140,000 per hour measure in what we classify as a large retailer, and I work for a tier 1 vendor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, as a web framework, RoR does not impose any restrictions on the work load limit.

The work load limit depends on:

1. How many machines to serve the request
2. Complexity of your business logic, which determines work load limit of single machine
3. Any bottleneck in bandwidth, or database disk I/O?

Comment: Are there any examples, beyond the Twitter example that's often cited, of other medium to high transactional sites in ROR?

Comment: RoR is also heavily used inside Amazon.